# Why doesn't Json.net properly serialize a class derived from TreeNode?

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

I have a class inherited from `TreeNode` that when I try to serialize it just returns a string that's not a JSON string (as I expected).

For example:

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new A());
```

output:

```
"TreeNode: "
```

Where `A` is defined as:

```
public class A : TreeNode { public int x { get; set; } }
```

If I remove the `TreeNode` inheritance, the output is:

```
{"x":0}
```

Why it doesn't serialize property if it's inherited from `TreeNode`?
NOTE: I filter my class to serialize only the public properties of my `A` class, using a contract:

```
public class ShouldSerializeContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    private List<string> propertiesNames;

    public ShouldSerializeContractResolver(Type type)
    {
        this.propertiesNames =
            type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly)
            .Select(p => p.Name)
            .ToList();
    }

    protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        JsonProperty property = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);

        property.ShouldSerialize =
            instance =>
            {
                return propertiesNames.Contains(property.PropertyName);
            };

        return property;
    }
}
```

And then serialize the object using:

```
ShouldSerializeContractResolver contract = new ShouldSerializeContractResolver(typeof(CustomTreeNode));
            JsonSerializerSettings jsonSerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings() { ContractResolver = contract };
            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(groups, Formatting.Indented, jsonSerializerSettings);
```

but it returns the same invalid output as I mentioned in the start of topic.

Comment: What is `CustomTreeNode`? And `groups`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're talking about [`System.Windows.Forms.TreeNode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treenode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) then the reason you are seeing this behavior is because `TreeNode` has a [`[TypeConverter]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.typeconverterattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) attribute applied to it, which causes Json.Net to serialize it to a simple string value instead of an object.

You can get it to work the way you want in a couple of different ways.

1. Apply a `[JsonObject]` attribute to your custom TreeNode class

   ```
   [JsonObject]
   public class A : TreeNode
   { 
       ...
   }
   ```
2. Or, override the `CreateContract()` method in your custom `ContractResolver` such that it explicitly creates an object contract for your custom type:

   ```
   public class ShouldSerializeContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
   {
       private Type myType;
       private List<string> propertiesNames;

       public ShouldSerializeContractResolver(Type type)
       {
           myType = type;

           this.propertiesNames =
               type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly)
               .Select(p => p.Name)
               .ToList();
       }

       protected override JsonContract CreateContract(Type objectType)
       {
           if (objectType == myType)
           {
               return CreateObjectContract(objectType);
           }
           return base.CreateContract(objectType);
       }

       protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
       {
           JsonProperty property = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);

           property.ShouldSerialize =
               instance =>
               {
                   return propertiesNames.Contains(property.PropertyName);
               };

           return property;
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: I used not only the class but the [JsonObject] attribute too (when deserializing it's needed). Thanks